Why does my Ubuntu install freeze upon boot?
I haven't used my Ubuntu for a few days and suddenly it freezes upon boot up.
Every time I boot up Ubuntu it'll be stucked on the desktop and will not respond to any action expect shutting down (I had it on auto login so no login screen).
Reboot does not help. I have been using current Ubuntu for months and it has been working fine. My Ubuntu setup is in my D drive alongside with Windows 10 (dualboot).
How can I unfreeze my Ubuntu?
OS:

Windows 10 22H2
Ubuntu 20.04

Device specifications:

Device Name: LAPTOP-PHNQKA0S
Processor: 11th Gen Intel(R) Core(TM) i9-11900H @ 2.50GHz 2.50 GHz
Installed Memory (RAM): 32.0 GB (31.7 GB usable)
Device ID: 2991DE01-54D3-4C02-A58D-161E402ABDEA
Product ID: 00325-82185-87765-AAOEM
System Type: 64-bit Operating System, x64-based Processor
Pen and Touch: Pen support

Debugging attempts:
reference: Modifying Linux kernel parameters in Grub

Adding nomodeset at the end of "linux" line. Result: freeze on this screen upon boot up:

Adding nouveau.noaccel=1 at the end of "linux" line.
Replace quiet splash with noapic noacpi nosplash irqpoll. Result: Both methods still end up with frozen Ubuntu desktop
Tried switch to tty and sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall, the freeze won't let me get into tty in the first place.
Boot recovery mode, tried every option (however it seems like only dpkg did something), reboot and the freeze remain.(btw network failed something in the command line)


Start by using a contemporary Ubuntu release (e.g. Ubuntu 24.04) instead of a 4 years old release that's older than your hardware. If you notice the sane problem then that's a proper question.

@ChanganAuto There are many reason why I use 20.04, the main being ros noetic, which is most capable in 20.04. I could probably get it running on 22.04 or 24.04, but it will probably cause more problem then using old version ubuntu.

20.04 is LTS and still supported IIRC. And (from experience) upgrading between versions dosen't always go smoothly

@JourneymanGeek but 20.04 is used quite often in my experience (many git project etc), I doubt it will have severe flaw in it.
